# Magento 1.7.2 - How to include CMS pages in topmenu?

Tags: php, magento, menu

I have created 2 CMS pages in magento 1.7.2

Lets say the cms page "About Us" which is the URL

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/about-company/?___store=default
```

and the page "Customer Service" which is the URL    `http://localhost/magento/index.php/customer-service/?___store=default`

In my HEADER.PHTML the line   getChildHtml('topMenu') ?> shows the topmenu.

the problem is that the 'topMenu' contains **only the categories** created by **Catalog->Manage Categories**

**What is the appropriate way to include the 2 cms pages ("About Us" and "Customer Service")
in the 'topMenu' ?**

*Thank you for your help !*

Comment: you have to code it in `topmenu.phtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static block for cms pages from admin and write the below format code

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="about-company"}}">About Company</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store direct_url="customer-service"}}">Customer Service</a></li>
</ul>
```

Call this block in topmenu.phtml (/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml) page

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_pages')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: If i place it like this I loose the css of the topmenu....<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_pages')->toHtml();?>
    </ul>
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_pages')->toHtml();?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>  Any suggestion of how to keek the css for also for the block ? Where should I place the line ?

Comment: remove <ul></ul> from block page

Comment: Thank you very much Monojit...it worked like a charm! But In case I want to place a category of magento between "About Company" and "Customer Service" is that possible ? Or because is a block we cannot "break" it? If you know this I would be greatfull

Comment: Yes it's possible but till now I didn't do like that.You can check http://futureplanmedia.com/magento-exclude-categories-from-top-category-menu-navigation/ and http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/custom-category-menu-navigation-in-magento/ if it helps you.thanks.

Comment: You can break the navigation menu then i think it will be possible.can you plz vote my answer.

Comment: It says that it requires more than 15 reputation.Thanks for your answers!Really helpful.When reputation will go up surely I will vote you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code under your /template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

```
<li title="<?php echo $this->__('About Company') ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>about-company"><?php echo $this->__('About Company') ?></a></li>
```